# List of Twitter clients that support Oauth?

Tags: gwibber, twitter, client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GUI Twitter clients: what are my options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4922/gui-twitter-clients-what-are-my-options)

Can we get a list of Twitter clients that support Oauth going?

Gnome:

[Gwibber](http://gwibber.com/)

KDE:

[Choqok](https://www.ohloh.net/p/choqok) [source](https://www.ohloh.net/p/choqok/download?package=choqok) >= beta 3 has oauth

Air:

[TweetDeck](https://www.tweetdeck.com/desktop/)

[Twhirl](http://www.twhirl.org/)

Comment: You don't need to link to the PPA version of gwibber, it's been fixed in Lucid.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on using free software - twhirl and TweetDeck (Adobe AIR apps) support Twitter's OAuth. Note that both of them support multiple accounts and can be used with status.net instances too.

Comment: I'll add Air apps to the list, though on x64 linux, Air is a tad spotty (and is the sole reason why my case fan kicks into high).

Comment: Those are free software too.

Comment: People generally mean "free as in freedom" rather than "free as in beer" in Linux circles.

Answer (score 1):

There is **Hotot**. You can found info about it [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/hotot-the-hottest-new-twitter-app-for-linux/).

Answer (score 0):

This [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~muffinresearch/+archive/gwibber-oauth) claims to support Oauth for Gwibber. and [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/twitters-oauthpocalypse-today-upgrade.html) is another workaround for Gwibber. As for me I am using yoono extension of firefox for twitter updates.

Answer (score -1):

At this point, if a client does not support OAuth, it won't work. Check the bug tracker for complaints about the program not working to see if they support it or not.

Comment: Thus my question.