# What microblogging clients are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, twitter

What GUI Twitter clients are there for Ubuntu?

Please include reasons why you like - or highlight features that make a client unique. Please also keep to one client per answer.

Comment: This post - as is - is too open ended, and subjective. Please provide guidelines, everyone's opinion of "friendly" is different. Furthermore you may wish to make this simple "What are available Twitter clients for Ubuntu" which would allow users to more objectively answer your question.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: I meant anything that doesn't involve the command line.

Comment: Could you please update your post to reflect that? Also: Converted to CW.

Answer (score 12):

## [Hotot](http://hotot.org/)

I've been using [hotot](http://hotot.org/), and I am very satisfied, because:

- It's lightweight
- It has preview for images
- Threaded Conversations
- Extensions Support (although there aren't any at the moment, AFAIK)
- It just **looks** good

There are a few quirks, this client is new, but improving rapidly.

Add the 'ppa:hotot-team' ppa([see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102) for how to add a ppa) then install hotot via the software center.

Comment: Good. It's faster than gwibber and it installs cleanly in 10.10 (unlike Pino).

Comment: Also it has a chrome app as well.

Answer (score 7):

## [Gwibber](http://gwibber.com)

Gwibber is the default Microblogging client since 10.04 and offers great features and includes other services (aside from Twitter).

- Integrates with Message Indicator
- Works post-Authpocalypse
- Multiple Column support
- Multiple Account support

[image: Gwibber]

Installation instructions [a la wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Gwibber)

Comment: I like it, but at this point it does seem to leak memory quite badly.

Comment: It's tremendously slow :/

Answer (score 7):

## Turpial

Turpial is an excellent and lightweight twitter client. The only thing missing is multi account support.

[image: Turpial]
Add the 'ppa:effie-jayx/turpial' ppa([see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102) for how to add a ppa) then install turpial via the software center.

[Official Website](http://turpial.org.ve/features/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pino](http://pino-app.appspot.com/)

A great client for Linux that runs on the Vala language.  There is a PPA to install from.

The PPAs that are needed are [here](http://pino-app.appspot.com/downloads).

[image]

Comment: Can you link up the PPA? It would make this answer much more useful

Comment: Added the download link; the PPAs are under that link.

Comment: Pino is great. Hope it makes into the repos by 11.04

Comment: PPA doesn't work for 10.10. :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Tweetdeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/)

Is an Adobe AIR application that works with Twitter, Facebook, and Buzz.  It also has experimental status.net support.

Comment: no longer an option - tweetdeck for air is no longer supported.

Comment: I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Yoono](http://www.yoono.com/desktop_features.html)

Although I have only used it as firefox addon. It runs as desktop application as well I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Choqok](http://choqok.gnufolks.org/) is a KDE app that works well.  It uses a lot of KDE libraries, so be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DestroyTwitter](http://destroytwitter.com/)

It's Adobe AIR but has a super low memory footprint < 25MB.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pwytter](http://www.pwytter.com/)

The client is developing. Yet what I like is its portable and can be tweaked to your need if you know python. Since It is developed in python with tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

The [Deskbar](http://philwilson.org/blog/2007/03/post-to-twitter-from-ubuntu-deskbar) applet is another way to post to twitter.  Deskbar is in the Ubuntu Repos.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[gTwitter](http://code.google.com/p/gtwitter/) is a lightweight twitter app that uses GTK+.  See the link for an Ubuntu PPA.

Answer (score 0):

For those fans of XMonad, like myself, you should really take a look at: http://ooxo.org/dtwitzen/

Which is a dzen twitter thingumbob-doodle-whatzit-of-awesomeness if you are into that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Pidgin Messenger** - In the Software Center

I'm already using it for Google Talk and it supports multiple twitter accounts. It lists the messages in a simple one line format as opposed to fancy formatting which removes from screen real estate.

It sits on the Notification bar and as Tweets come through it pops up (configurable) which is handy as I follow very few "people" so the information is generally of interest. But as thats configurable if you follow 100s then it will just be one big list in your "chat session".

To tweet you just "reply" to the chat user which is the twitter account.