# What TweetDeck, or Gwibber alternatives are there that support Facebook?

Tags: software-recommendation, facebook

TweetDeck I really enjoyed until I installed Ubuntu, as Adobe doesn't have a 64-bit version of Adobe AIR (which is  necessary to run TweetDeck) so I can't use it anymore. Are there any alternatives that support **Facebook**?

Note - there is a similar question - but this has been reopened to be specific to facebook support:

[What microblogging clients are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4922/what-microblogging-clients-are-available)

Comment: Have you tried Adobe's method for installing Air on 64, it just uses the 32 bit .bins. Thats how I got destroy Twitter working. I think this is how:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/521/cpsid_52132.html

Comment: I have actually. Unfortunately, TweakDeck doesn't work 100% with this hacked version of AIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind running in a browser then [Tweetdeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/), [Hootsuite](http://hootsuite.com/) and [Seesmic](http://seesmic.com/) all run on Chrome(ium) and the last two on Firefox. Personally I run Tweetdeck under Chrome and running these services in a browser is probably the best way forward. Adobe have stopped development of Air for linux, so do not expect much new software in Ubuntu using it.

Answer (score 1):

**You can easily install Adobe Air 64-bit :**

[How do I install Adobe AIR?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47560/how-do-i-install-adobe-air-64bit)

So Download and install [TweetDeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/desktop/).

Comment: Hi. I actually tried using that exact method a few weeks ago. Sadly, TweetDeck was extremely buggy when using the 64-bit version of Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying ouy Digsby, as soon as a Linux version will be released (later this year, they say). You may signup to be announced when it's available at http://www.digsby.com/signup/maclinux/?os=linux .

Comment: Digsby is comming for mac and linux for about 2 years!
  
Quote from [here](http://forum.digsby.com/viewtopic.php?id=7214):  
LOL don't hold your breath.  Not like it's hard to convert the source code over to Linux and compile it on Linux but I've been waiting for a **good 2 years** now probably and still no word.  I've given up on Digsby...  Use Konversation or Pidgin for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

TweetDeck, one of the most popular desktop clients for Twitter and facebook.
 you can post updates to Twitter, Facebook, or both simultaneously.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Hotot](http://hotot.org/) ,
or you can try TweetDeck on chrome browser.

Comment: I looked, but couldn't find any information on whether or not Hotot supports Facebook, do you know?

Comment: Hotot does not support Facebook AFAICT.

Comment: -1 Because Hotot does not support Facebook, and it [never will](http://code.google.com/p/hotot/issues/detail?id=168&can=1&q=facebook&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Reporter%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary).

Comment: When answering questions, try to be relevant to the question (and any important details).

Comment: @jrg [Never will?](http://code.google.com/p/hotot/issues/detail?id=168&can=1&q=facebook&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Reporter%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) "We don't have plans to support Facebook **at this time**... Anyway, **patches are welcomed**."

Comment: @EliahKagan more accurately, it won't unless people submit patches. You and I both know how likely that is.