# Is tweetdeck for desktop open source?

Tags: 11.04, gwibber

Is tweetdeck for desktop open source? If not are there any open source alternatives to Gwibber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweetdeck is not open source. A list of twitter clients is here:

- [What microblogging clients are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4922/what-microblogging-clients-are-available)